# Is there any way to manage resources in WPF through Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, resources

Is there any way I can manage resources through the GUI? Or the only way possible is through XAML code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Expression Blend to do this. Not sure Visual Studio supports this as good as Blend does.

[alt Resources in Blend http://i.expression.microsoft.com/dd279539.newsletter_s_resources(en-us,MSDN.10).png](http://i.expression.microsoft.com/dd279539.newsletter_s_resources(en-us,MSDN.10).png)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can see a preview of resources, just like you can in Blend.